# Object Oriented JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, constructor

I created an animation using JQuery Code, which will simply create a stalk of colored divs one after another. Important point is- I wanted to repeat this function 2 times more and I achieved that by creating 2 more functions and call it in the order of execution with '.then()'.

```
function boxA(){
    var d = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function() {
        var $box = $(".ruleblk1 div");
        var n = $box.length;  
        var x=0;
        var colorval=['2a0d00','bf4e00','e2281a','ffc015','60a900'];
        $( ".ruleblk1 div" ).last().css('background','#'+colorval[0]+'').fadeTo( "1000", 1, function showNext() {           
        $( this ).prev( "div" ).css('background','#'+colorval[++x]+'').fadeTo( "1000",1, showNext);
        }); 
         d.resolve();
        },100);
    return d.promise();     
    };
```

It's HTML part is

```
<div class="ruleblk1 blkcont">
<div>FirstBlock</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
<div class="ruleblk2 blkcont">
<div>Second Block</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
<div class="ruleblk3 blkcont">
<div>Third Block</div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

My Question is I don't want to repeat the same function for each associated DOM element (ruleblk2, ruleblk3 etc) and thought of creating a single constructor function for each blocks animation and create 3 functions as an instance of Constructor function and pass DOM element name (for instance .rulebl3 div) as parameter. What will be the best way to achieve this?

Thank You

Comment: Why don't you just pass an argument to `boxA`?

Comment: @plalx Yes, that is possible. But in this particular case, I'm supposed to execute - 'boxA().then(anotherfunc).then(boxB).then(anotherfunc).then(boxC)' -like this. So I have to create separate functions or put in a loop or again call back in side boxA() for boxB and boxC.  That's why I thought of create a constructor function for animating one block and  create 3 functions in which we just pass the DOM name as argument and pass it to the constructor.

Comment: @Shine What's wrong with `boxA('ruleblk1').then(...).then(boxA.bind(null, 'ruleblk2')).then(...)` ?